# Do the current moderators stay moderators?

Tags: support, election

Is this first-ever election to replace the current moderators, or do the current moderators stay moderators? Do our friendly neighborhood mods @voretaq7, @Lnafziger, and @egid have to nominate themselves if they want to keep the role?

Answer (score 10):

> Do our friendly neighborhood mods @voretaq7, @Lnafziger, and @egid have to nominate themselves if they want to keep the role?

That's exactly the case: existing moderators will need to run for election if they want to keep the job. Since our current moderators were serving as "pro-tempore" moderators, their terms expire when the first election is completed.

For the moderators that will be elected, there is no expiration date, but they will be free to resign at any time.