# A couple of election questions

Tags: discussion, election, election-2016

2 quick questions, mostly out of curiosity:

1. Are there still going to be 3 mods?
2. Are the votes weighed by rep?

Comment: My phone said this question didn't go thru, thus the dupe post. Chin someone delete one of them. I can't delete

Answer (score 7):

> Are there still going to be 3 mods?

Yes, from the [election page:](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1)

> moderator candidates: 7
>
> moderator positions available: 3

Per another [meta question](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2908/1696), all current pro-temp mods must run again, meaning the 3 positions up for current election are the only 3 going forward.

> Are the votes weighed by rep?

No, from the [election page](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1) again:

> We will calculate the winners using OpenSTV with the Meek STV method, which automatically weights users' votes in the way that does the most good for the candidates they have selected, in order of preference.

So the votes will be weighted by the order each voter chose, but not by the rep of voters or candidates.

Comment: Sorry. Didn't see that info. I'm using my phone and it was of the side of the screen.